# C# Object to json mapping

Tags: c#, json

i have a problem:

I want to map the following C# Object to a json structure:

```
public class TestObj{
        [JsonProperty("full_name")]
        public string Name{ get; set; }


        public City City{ get; set; } = new City();
}

public class City{
        [JsonProperty("city_name")]
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("zip")]
        public string ZIP{ get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("country")]
        public string Country{ get; set; }
}
```

And i want the json to look like this:

```
{
  "full_name": "abx",
  "zip": "xyz",
  "country":"xxx",
  "city_name":"bb"
}
```

I do not want the city to be an object in JSON.
I know that this is not the best solution, but I can not change the structure of the json, therefore I must map the object in this specific way.
I could create a jsonstring in this format, but wanted to ask if anyone knows a better way than using a stringbuilder?

Comment: ```[JsonIgnore]``` might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're talking about customizing the structure and not just the property names/visibility, you likely need to change the object structure.  That isn't necessarily to mean that you have to change your models, but that you can project your models into a structure specifically for the serialization.

For example, you might serialize like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
    full_name = myObj.Name,
    zip = myObj.City.ZIP,
    country = myObj.City.Country,
    city_name = myObj.City.Name
});
```

If this has to be done in multiple places then you can avoid repeating the logic by encapsulating the conversion into a method on the model, perhaps called something like "ToSerializedObject".  Instead of using an anonymous object then you might create a specific DTO object for this purpose.  So overall perhaps something like:

```
public class TestObjDTO
{
    [JsonProperty("full_name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("zip")]
    public string ZIP{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("country")]
    public string Country{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("city_name")]
    public string CityName{ get; set; }
}

public class TestObj
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public City City{ get; set; } = new City();

    public TestObjDTO ToSerializedObject()
    {
        return new TestObjDTO
        {
            Name = this.Name,
            ZIP = this.City.ZIP,
            Country = this.City.Country,
            CityName = this.City.Name
        };
    }
}

public class City
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public string ZIP{ get; set; }

    public string Country{ get; set; }
}
```

And then you'd use it as such:

```
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj.ToSerializedObject());
```

Basically you can arrange it however you like, but the point is that the easiest path here is likely to just create the object structure you want as a DTO rather than trying to customize the serializer to perform the conversion for you.